# The name "WriteLine" does not exist in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am developing a console project in C#. The code is separated into some files. The compiler shows this error:

```cs
IDE1007 The name 'WriteLine' does not exist in the current context
```

I used `Console.Writeline()` method in other files (`Program.cs` and `LaptopBLL.cs` to be precise) and the compiler didn't report any error.
I checked `SalesManagerMenu.cs` for the `using System;` line. Naturally, it was there, thouugh the error remains. Here is the full file:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LaptopStore
{
    internal class SalesManagerMenu
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nSample text here");
    }
}
```

How do I make it work with `Console.WriteLine()` properly?

Comment: You cannot put statements directly into a class, only in a method.

Comment: Looks lile putting it into a method really helped. Thank you, herr Klaus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with `WriteLine`, it's the fact you can't have statements directly under a class - they need to be in a method or a constructor. E.g.:

```
namespace LaptopStore
{
    internal class SalesManagerMenu
    {
        static public void Main(String[] args) // Here!
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nSample text here");
        }
    }
}
```